# Teams Bot with node.js: How to update a message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a working C# bot for Teams client, but I need to have the same in node.js.
I have a problem when I need to update a message I sent, without the Context.

In my C# code, I send a message and save the activity id and the conversation Id where it is sent.
To update this activity (when required), I create a new activity and use this saved id:

```
var activityIdSaved = "xxx";
var conversationId_saved = "yyyyy";

var activity = Bot.Schema.Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
activity.Id = activityIdSaved; // set Id (saved activity Id)
activity.Text = "This is updated text";

await connectorClient.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync(conversationId_saved, activityIdSaved, (Bot.Schema.Activity)activity);
```

This works properly in C#, but I can not find which method to use in node.js for the same purpose...

Thanks,

Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same thing except that `ConnectorClient` needs a `baseUri`. Something like this:

```js
const connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new MicrosoftAppCredentials('<yourAppId>', '<yourAppPassword>'), { baseUri: teamsServiceUrl });

const activity = MessageFactory.text("This is updated text");
activity.id = activityIdSaved;

await connectorClient.conversations.updateActivity(conversationId_saved, activityIdSaved, activity as Activity);
```

`teamsServiceUrl` varies by where the user communicates from. For me, it's `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/`, but you'll likely need to grab it dynamically from `activity.serviceUrl`.

I'm not sure why you need to manually set `activity.id` and also pass it into `updateActivity`, but I couldn't get it to work, otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

@Deigo Since you have already implemented this in C#, here is a sample to [update message in NodeJS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/dialogs/examples/teams/UpdateCardMsgDialog.ts). Please try out the sample and let us know if you face any issues.